# Stored procedure doesn't allow null parameters even the parameter represent accept nulls?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I saw many questions on stack overflow, non of them touched my own problem

> procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

I created this SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[spAddCustomer]
    @cuName varchar(50),
    @cuAddress varchar(50),
    @cuMobile varchar(50),
    @cuImage image,
    @cityId int,
    @exist int output
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Cu_Mobile FROM tblCustomers WHERE Cu_Mobile = @cuMobile)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblCustomers (Cu_Name, Cu_Address, Cu_Mobile, Cu_Image, City_ID)
        VALUES (@cuName, @cuAddress, @cuMobile, @cuImage, @cityId)

        SET @exist = 1
    END
    ELSE
        SET @exist = 0
END
```

In my Data Access Layer I have this method that is responsible for non-query commands:

```
public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string query, CommandType type, params SqlParameter[] arr)
{
    int outParam;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(arr);
    cmd.CommandType = type;

    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    foreach (SqlParameter param in arr)
    {
        if (param.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output)
        {
            outParam = (int)cmd.Parameters[param.ToString()].Value;
            return outParam;
        }
    }

    return i;
}
```

The method responsible for creating parameters:

```
public static SqlParameter CreateParameter(string name, SqlDbType type, object value, ParameterDirection pd = ParameterDirection.Input)
{
    SqlParameter pr = new SqlParameter();
    pr.ParameterName = name;
    pr.Direction = pd;
    pr.SqlDbType = type;
    pr.SqlValue = value;

    return pr;
}
```

And this method in the Business Layer, pass the arguments from the Presentation Layer

```
public static int spAddCustomer(string cusName, string cusAddress, string cusMobile, byte[] arrImg, int cityId)
{
    DataAccessLayer.Open();

    int i = DataAccessLayer.ExecuteNonQuery("spAddCustomer", CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        DataAccessLayer.CreateParameter("@cuName", SqlDbType.VarChar, cusName),
        DataAccessLayer.CreateParameter("@cuAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, cusAddress),
        DataAccessLayer.CreateParameter("@cuMobile", SqlDbType.VarChar, cusMobile),
        DataAccessLayer.CreateParameter("@cuImage", SqlDbType.Image, arrImg),
        DataAccessLayer.CreateParameter("@cityId", SqlDbType.Int, cityId),
        DataAccessLayer.CreateParameter("@exist", SqlDbType.Int, null, ParameterDirection.Output));

    DataAccessLayer.Close();

    return i;
}
```

When the user Click add a new record is inserted into the table (`tblCustomers`)

```
private void btnAU_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] imgArr;

    if (PbCustomer.Image == null)
           imgArr = null;
    else
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        PbCustomer.Image.Save(ms, PbCustomer.Image.RawFormat);
        imgArr = ms.ToArray();
    }

    int cityId = int.Parse(cmbCities.SelectedValue.ToString());

    try
    {
        int exist = CustomerClass.spAddCustomer(txtName.Text, txtAddress.Text, txtMobile.Text, imgArr, cityId);

        if (exist == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A new customer has been saved");
            txtAddress.Text = txtMobile.Text = txtName.Text = "";
            PbCustomer.Image = null;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("A customer with the same mobile number\nalready exists, add new number!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But when I click the `Add` button (passing null image), I get this error:

> procedure or function 'spAddCustomer' expects parameter '@cuImage'
>   which was not supplied

Despite the table `tblCustomers` accept null values

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see what values are actually being passed in?   And can you post the code for `CreateParameter`?

Comment: Where/what is `DataAccessLayer.CreateParameter`?

Comment: also check your begin and ending `{ }` they seem to not line up

Comment: Note that an empty `TextBox` has a value of `String.Empty`, not `null`! Do things get better is you convert `""` to `null`?

Comment: better yet do something like this if the TextBox.Text is = to string.Empty
`DataAccessLayer.CreateParameter("@cuName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cusName) ? DBNULL.Value : cusName;`

Comment: I've added the method CreateParameter. the debugger doesn't tell me more than the SQL exception that I'mm passing null value!

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @marc_s, I know about `text` but I didn't know about `image`

Comment: Can you please check my answer, it solved the problem, but from my beginning experience in SQL , I don't know if it solves the problem in a practical way or not!

Comment: Your solution is also fine, you just made those parameters in Stored Proc optional. There is no big difference b/w two solutions, in your case it depends on your design preferences.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just found that I can set default values for the parameter in the stored procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spAddCustomer]
@cuName varchar(50)=null,
@cuAddress varchar(50)=null,
@cuMobile varchar(50)= null,
@cuImage image= null,
@cityId int= null,
@exist int output
```

And this solved my problem!
This is helpful specifically with null images from the PictureBox, since I have a helper method that checks for empty strings.

Answer (score 8):

You need to check your input for null and use `DBNull.Value` when you creating the parameters. If you pass just `null` as a parameter - ADO.Net will ignore that.

**EDIT:**

You can add that check into your custom method `DataAccessLayer.CreateParameter()`

Comment: `DataAccessLayer.CreateParameter("@cuName", SqlDbType.VarChar, String.IsNullOrWhitespace(cusName) ? DBNull.Value : cusName),`

Comment: I would rather fix DataAccessLayer.CreateParameter() method itself to check for null/whitespace parameter instead of using ternary operator ?: everytime.